# Why can't I boot from my cloned drive?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, clonezilla, cloning

I am trying to replace an HDD with a SSD on an old Samsung Series 5 Ultra. I have tried cloning the drive multiple ways:

1. Tried with Macrium - drive wouldn't boot and got stuck in a loop restarting after the Samsung screen.
2. Tried with DriveImage XML - same issue
3. Tried with Clonezilla - this was more successful and booted the first few times, but after about 24 hours of the machine being switched off, when booting I get a "disk read error" requiring a restart, and the machine then takes 20 minutes to boot. This issue repeats itself every 24 hours or so
4. Tried reinstalling Windows 10 from USB as per the microsoft website guidance - this appeared to install ok but would not restart at the end of the process (or rather, wouldn't turn off - just went to a black screen with the power light still on). I manually turned the machine off, but it would not boot from the new install.

There do not appear to be any issues with the new drive when checking diskmanagement - and I have cleaned it several times just in case. I can still use it as an external mass storage device. I also know the hardward is compatible (the drive is a Kioxia Exceria 500gb) because last week I put  one into an identical laptop, but on that occasion did a clean install of Chrome OS Flex and the system works perfectly.

Is there a common problem that might explain all 4 issues? I cannot believe I am having 4 separate issues here.

Comment: What type of SSD - SATA or NVMe _(it's likely only a SATA SSD would be supported)_? After imaging, it's usually required to execute `BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD`

Comment: Does the computer work well with the HDD (not the SSD) ?

Comment: @JW0914 Agreed, but if the OP reinstalled Windows (#4) that's a moot point.

Comment: The drive is a SATA III SSD. The computer works just fine with the HDD - this is just an upgrade since I wanted faster boot times on it.